# Adding Autocomplete with Javascript to Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, qualtrics

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete feature to Qualtrics online survey management software. As directed [in this feature on the Qualtrics](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/question-options-advanced/add-javascript/) website, I've added the main features of the code to the header of it's Look and Feel section.

```
<br />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script><script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();  
 $j(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "Selection 1",
  "Selection 2",
  "Selection 3"
];
$j( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

Also, I've added this to the specific question block I want the autocomplete feature to be applied to.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
});
});
```

I receive no error messages, the text input field just does not call up the tags.

Comment: You're loading jQuery UI before you're loading jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try changing "#tags" to ".InputText".  #tags refers to an id that doesn't exist in Qualtrics.  .InputText is a class used on text input fields.

Put this in the Qualtrics header (as Anthony recommended):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();  
</script>
```

And this in your question (with NO Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload) so it only applies to the page with your question on it:

```
$j(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "Selection 1",
        "Selection 2",
        "Selection 3"
    ];
    $j( ".InputText" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick note. First of all this answer is correct, I just tested it. Second, you will likely want to add some styling to the submenu to make it look a bit better. Such as:


.ui-menu-item{
background-color: white;
font-size: 1.5em; 
width: 150px;
}

.ui-menu-item:hover{
background-color: grey;
font-size: 1.5em; 
width: 150px;
}