# Qualtrics autocompleted answer not captured in responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, qualtrics

I'm implementing an autocomplete feature in a Qualtrics survey. When the user types into a textbox, a list of items containing the user-inputted text appears. The user can choose to fill the textbox with an item from this list.

However, when I choose from the list, the text that I inputted appears in the response data instead of the choice. For example, I type "A" and choose "Apple." "Apple" appears in the survey textbox, but "A" is recorded in the data. If you continue to edit the inputted text, whatever is shown in the text box is recorded in the data. However, I do not expect the survey respondents to edit the text once they've selected their answer. This is an issue in Internet Explorer and Chrome. "Apple" appears in the data when I answer the survey using Firefox.

I used a solution from a previous question: [Unsolved - Adding Autocomplete with Javascript to Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952275/unsolved-adding-autocomplete-with-javascript-to-qualtrics), but the same problem (along with other issues) appear.

This is the code I'm using in Look and Feel, Advanced:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><script>

var qtrix = new Object();

qtrix.$ = jQuery.noConflict();

qtrix.helloWorld = function() {
  alert("Hello world!");
};

qtrix.autoCompleteList = [ ];

function qtrixSetAutoCompleteList(list) {
  qtrixAutoCompleteList = list;
}

qtrix.accentMap = {
    "á": "a",
    "à": "a",
    "ä": "a",

    "é": "e",
    "è": "e",
    "ë": "e",

    "í": "i",
    "ì": "i",
    "ï": "i",

    "ó": "o",
    "ò": "o",
    "ö": "o",

    "ú": "u",
    "ù": "u",
    "ü": "u"
};

qtrix.articles = [
    "the",
    "le",
    "l'",
    "la",
    "die",
    "das",
    "der"
];

qtrix.stripAccents = function(term) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
    ret += qtrix.accentMap[term.charAt(i)] || term.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
};

qtrix.cleanTerm = function(term) {
    term = term.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < qtrix.articles.length; i++) {
    if (term.substring(0, qtrix.articles[i].length) == qtrix.articles[i]) {
        return term.substring(qtrix.articles[i].length, term.length)
        .trim();
    }
    }
    return term;
};

qtrix.addAutoComplete = function(id, list) {
    qtrix.$(id).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        request.term = qtrix.cleanTerm(request.term);
        var matcher =
        new RegExp(qtrix.$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), 
               "i");
        response(qtrix.$.grep(list, function(value) {
        value = value.label || value.value || value;
        return matcher.test(value) || 
            matcher.test(qtrix.stripAccents(value));
        }));
    }
    });
};

</script>
```

This is the code in the question's javascript box:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    qtrix.addAutoComplete("#QR\\~QID6", [
"Item 1",
"Item 2",
"Item 3",
"Item 3000"
        ]);
});
```

I'm unfamiliar with Javascript and fairly new to this level of customization in Qualtrics. I would appreciate any guidance or leads. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a link to your question? Do you want the answers limited to items on the list, or can the answers be open ended?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm sorry, I can't provide a link to the question. The question asks which college a student is enrolled it. The question is open-ended ended, but we'd like to encourage some conformity, especially when dealing with multiple campuses. For example, some students might write University of California. The autocomplete will show the different UC campuses, hopefully prompting the student to specify.